# How to prevent child routes in Vue.js from losing styles when the page refreshes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli-3

My routing for my site works fine but the problem arises when I hit the refresh button.

On a base route for example `http://localhost:8080/employers` the page or component style remains the same but when I refresh a child route for example `http://localhost:8080/employers/google` all the style for this component will be lost.

Any help on how to resolve this problem will be appreciated

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router' 
// import store from './store.js'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [        
        {
            path: '/',
            component: () => import('./views/Home.vue'),
            children: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    component: () => import("./views/HomePage.vue"),
                },
                {
                    path: '/jobs',
                    name: 'jobs',
                    component: () => import('./views/JobListings.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: '/job/:id',
                    name: 'job',
                    component: () => import('./views/JobDetails.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: '/login',
                    name: 'login',
                    component: () => import('./views/Login.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: '/register',
                    name: 'register',
                    component: () => import('./views/Register.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: '/forgotpassword',
                    name: 'forgotpassword',
                    component: () => import('./views/ForgotPassword.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: '/verify',
                    name: 'verify',
                    component: () => import('./views/Verify.vue')
                }, 
            ],
        },


        {
            path: '/employer',
            component: () => import('@/views/Employers.vue'),
            children: [
                {
                    path: '', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Profile.vue')                    
                },
                {
                    path: 'profile', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Profile.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'post',
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/PostJob.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'listings', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Listings.vue')
                }, 
                {
                    path: 'settings', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Listings.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'editresume', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Listings.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'closeaccount', 
                    component: () => import('./views/Employers/Listings.vue')
                },
            ]
        },

        // jobseekers route
        {
            path: '/jobseeker', 
            component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Home.vue'),
            children: [
                {
                    path: '', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Profile.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'resume', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Resume.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'profile', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Profile.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'settings', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Settings.vue')
                },
                {
                    path: 'applications', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Applications.vue')
                },                
                {
                    path: 'close', 
                    component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Close.vue')
                },
            ]
        },

        {
            path: '/jobseeker/:page',
            component: () => import('@/views/Jobseekers/Profile.vue'),
        },

        {
            path: '/search/:region/:keyword',
            component: () => import('./views/JobListings.vue')
        },

        // not found route
        {
            path: '*',
            name: '404',
            component: () => import('./views/404.vue')
        }
    ]
})

export default router
```

Comment: Corrected typos, escaped localhost links

Comment: Are they lost for good or just for a split second?

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is not with your routes**, but how you write your css.

1. I recommend using a scoped style for in component styling (only this component will use the styles).
2. if more than one components are going to share styling, you can use css files separately.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are loading the components on-demand.

When you navigate from `/employers` to `/employers/google` route, there are some CSS styles from `/employers` route that are being reused in your `/employers/google` route.
So when you reload `http://localhost:8080/employers/google` route, you are unable to obtain the styles from `/employers` which causes your CSS to break.

My suggestion is to move common styles into one particular file and import it into the main file like `App.vue` so that they are loaded no matter which component is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also the same issue but I already include the CSS globally but it doesn't work,
finally, I try to change the router mode from history to hash it work.
Try in my case it works fine.

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: "hash",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: []
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add mode:"hash" after carrying out mode:"history", has shown below, and you are good to go

const router = new Router({
mode: "history",
mode: "hash",
routes: []
})